# I can not open Woost CMS because installer did not create the launcher

Tags: python, content-management-system

First of all, congratulations for the work with Woost!

I'm trying to install it, both in our desktop and in a Digital Ocean droplet, both running Ubuntu 16.04.01 (with Unity and command line, respectively), but in both cases the installer did not create the launcher.

I tried to run Woost using run.py script using (from woost folder):

```
bin/python scripts/run.py
```

It seems running, but could not create the launcher. I checked that gnome-terminal is installed.

I got the warning "Couldn't create stemmer for language 'ca'", but it is just a  warning.
I got an error with Mercurial, but I fixed using:

```
hg config --edit
```

In another terminal, I started zeo with (from woost folder):

```
sudo apt install python-zodb
scripts runzeo -f data/database.fs -a 127.0.0.1:13002
```

And then the first terminal (of run.py) answered:

> [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Listening for SIGHUP.
>   [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Listening for SIGTERM.
>   [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Listening for SIGUSR1.
>   [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Bus STARTING CherryPy Checker: The
>   Application mounted at '' has an empty config.
>
> [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Started monitor thread
>   '_TimeoutMonitor'. [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Started monitor
>   thread 'Autoreloader'. [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Serving on
>   127.0.0.1:13001 [13/Feb/2017:03:55:09] ENGINE Bus STARTED

I tried access with localhost:13001, but nothing happens.

I was looking for a open source, light, multilingual, drag & drop, and, if possible, based is Python CMS, and Woost would be the best choice. But I could not find Documentation and either not a community around this nice project.

Can somebody help?

Comment: I have a few questions: 1. Could you paste the woostproject.py line you used to create the project? 2. When you load http://localhost:13002 with your browser, what is the actual response? Do you see any output in the run.py terminal? Are there entries on the Apache log? 3. Can you inspect ~/.local/share/applications and see if there's a desktop file with your project's name? 4. Is there a _launcher_ folder at your project's root directory? If so, can you try running the _launch_ script it contains? That should bring up the project terminal.

Comment: Also, sorry, I skipped over the line "sudo apt install python-zodb". You definitely don't want to do that! All dependencies should be handled by the installer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Marti, thats it!
I opened Gnome Terminal, selected "Edit > Preferences > Profiles", and, as my system is set to Brazilian Portuguese locale, I had four "Sem nome" ("without name") profiles. I created a "Default" profile, and the installation completed!
I navigate to /.local/share/applications folder and there was a desktop file with my project name. I clicked in it and opened a terminal application with the tabs opened. But as it had an error, I had to install one more required package:

```
sudo apt-get install xtitle
```

Then I clicked in the desktop file again and everything were right.
Woost is running!
Thanks!

Comment: You should also see the launcher in your desktop's menu / application launcher (shout out if you don't, we haven't checked the integration with Unity, as we mostly run Gnome Shell). We'll make sure to add xtitle as one of the dependencies installed by "woostproject.py bootstrap". Also, we'll look for a robust way to detect the default profile for Gnome Terminal that works regardless of the system locale. Thank you for your feedback, I'm glad you could make it work.